# Portable Windows 10 Boot Issue

Tags: windows, boot, external-hard-drive, portable

A month ago I installed Windows 10 Build 1803 on a partition on my HDD. [WD Elements 1TB]

For almost a month, using Windows 10 by booting from my HDD I had no problems.
Everything had been properly updated and it worked like a charm.
I then decided to test just how portable it was because I had been using it on only one PC.
I tried booting the OS on a Lenovo laptop. For 2 days it worked pretty well that is I could continue my work with no interruptions.
On the third day I set the HDD's boot priority at the highest so I wouldn't have to choose the HDD everytime I booted. After the restart it was still working fine.

On the next restart, things started getting messy.
First Windows was stuck on the booting screen. After 3 consecutive hard  reboots, it started preparing the automatic repair tool but after the loading screen, the screen went all blank.

Now the thing is, when I unplug the HDD from the USB port, the automatic repair program progresses after the blank screen and asks for the preferred language. The automatic repair does not crash even though the OS is installed on the HDD which is unplugged.

I can navigate through the menus without plugging in the HDD but when I do plug it in, the program freezes and I am not able to move the cursor or choose anything.
When I unplug the HDD again, the repair tool starts working fine again.

Even when I unplug the HDD during the boot loading screen, the bot screen keeps on going indefinitely.

Currently, when my HDD is plugged in to the laptop, it freezes on startup that is it doesn't even make it to the "OS" booting screen unless I unplug the HDD.

I tried changing the boot priority back to normal from the BIOS but still I am not able to make any headway. I would rather not format the partition that I installed Windows on.

Any help or answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you use Windows To Go, it's not really portable, because drivers specific to one PC won't necessarily work on another. To be portable, it would have to download machine-specific drivers when booting or  contain *every* driver needed for all machines, a daunting task.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I think I used Windows To Go since I used Microsoft's official ISO image for the installation. Is there any difference between a Windows To Go machine and what I've done ?                                            And I still don't get why it worked flawlessly on the first two days of switching to a different device and then suddenly messed everything up.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go for Windows To Go.

Comment: So would it best that I gave up on booting the OS and start with a fresh install on a SSD ?